# Fastest path to Android development for a non-Java programmer

Tags: java, android

The decision to jump on the Android bandwagon has been made. The entire development environment has been installed and configured properly. I went through the steps suggested in http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html and even managed to "write" the Hello World application and run it on the emulator. :)

Unfortunately, however, I am not an experienced Java programmer and so, despite successfully completing all the suggested steps, and consulting an excellent speedy [Java tutorial for C++ programmers](http://triton.towson.edu/~mzimand/os/Lect2-java-tutorial.html), I feel that a lot is missing on the way to mastering Android development.

It would have been great to first master the Java world (note: I didn't say language, as Java is so much more than just syntax), then delve into Android, but in the real world there are deadlines to meet and so starting to develop/learn directly on Android is very tempting...

My question: Is it possible to develop good Android code while skipping the step of being an experienced Java programmer?

Do you know of a fast track that allows mastering both?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have come from .NET and it was very easy to pick it up.

I bought [Android Pro 2](http://apress.com/book/view/9781430226598) book and that was all I needed.

### UPDATE

Well, it seems that a few people have found the book really terrible because of typos and errors in the samples - and even in the book itself.

In any case, as you will find in the comments, this is by no means a definitive answer and please read Amazon reviews and choose the one you prefer. This worked for me since I need to understand the concept and then pick up the samples from Android documentations itself.

Comment: Yes, this is a great book and as long as you are familiar with OOP you should have no problem.

Comment: Thanks @Casey it is good to know that guys having done more Android also approve it.

Comment: @Aliostad and @CaseyB, I got my feet wet a little with this Pro Android 2 book and I must admit that it feels horrible to be (mis)guided by source code that doesn't work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096773/pro-android-2-what-are-gettextview-and-registermenu (if I were proficient enough to detect those typos/errors I wouldn't have needed the book).

Comment: @Aliostad Continuing to study from that Pro Android 2 book, I can now say that I have never seen a programming book with so many errors (not only typos) in my life. Ouch!

Comment: I am really sorry if i mislead you. When i looked around to buy a book on android in amazon, there were two around and acco, one which was written badly and one with errors in samples and typos. I chose second since i value understanding concepts over workable samples. And i was happy with the choice. I will update my ansser to include these.

Comment: @Aliostad FYI there is a typo in the **downloadable** version of listing 15-1. In the layout resource file, there should be **android:hint** (as in the book) and and not **android:hinttext** (as in the download).

Answer (score 2):

I believe a great share of Android developers come from other languages without any knowledge in Java at all. In fact all you need to know about Java in order to write Android code is it's syntax and core APIs: java.lang.*, java.util.*, java.net.*, java.io.* etc. The rest is Android-specific APIs and a profound Java programmer won't have much advantage over you in learning them.

Comment: Thanks and +1. In essence you are echoing @Aliostad's experience.