# Pro Android 2: What are getTextView() and registerMenu()?

Tags: android, android-activity

Listing 3-33 in the [acclaimed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4390290/fastest-path-to-anroid-development-for-a-non-java-programmer/4390314#4390314) Pro Android 2 book (source code can be found [here](http://apress.com/book/downloadfile/4529)) references two functions of which definitions I haven't been able to find in either the Android SDK or **all** listings in the book itself:

1. getTextView()
2. registerMenu()

What are these functions and where can they be found?

Comment: don't believe everything you read...

Comment: @sugarynugs I like that. :) +1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Helloe, Android. Say Hello");
        setContentView(tv);
        registerForContextMenu(tv);
}
```

will fix the problem of those methods not existing.

And no book I have read on Android is without its typos, missing bits etc.

PS. the menu will be a menu that shows up when you press down on the 'TextView'.

Comment: you are welcome.  i have the book, obviously, and was probably as impressed as you were.  i haven't found a book that goes beyond what you can learn from the SDK.  CommonsWare's book may but i don't have it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a `ContextMenu` to a `TextView` from your XML layout, you can use this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewId);
    registerForContextMenu(tv);
}
```